# Dockerizing React App but ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docker

I'm trying to turn this nodeJS video game into a docker container:
https://github.com/navignaw/TooManyChefs

But I'm getting "ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE" when I try to access the started docker container:
http://localhost:3000/

I think the issue is my dockerfile:

```
# pull official base image
FROM node:13.12.0-alpine

# set working directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH
COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . ./

EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Docker commands:

```
docker build -t hal/chefs . 
docker run -p 3000:3000 -d hal/chefs
```

Docker logs:

```
 docker logs 92928695b528a7ed4059bcc32af1d58a309f855294b48d49c60a2bb977755c4e

> TooManyChefs@ start /usr/src/app
> watchify -o js/bundle.js -v -d js/main.js
```

Can someone please give advice how I can fix or troubleshoot? I really appreciate your help!

-Hal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change the following line:

```
ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH
```

to :

```
ENV PATH /usr/src/app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH
```

#### Edit-01:

Also update your `npm install` command to following:

```
npm install --no-optional && npm cache clean --force
```

Comment: Do these commands seem right?
`docker build -t hal/chefs .` 
`docker run -p 3000:3000 -d hal/chefs`

Comment: Thank you! This is really helpful! Maybe its my commands. My logs look normal. I updated details.

Comment: @oreapot but it doesn't work yet, do my commands look correct? Any advice for how to troublshoot from here? Thank you

Comment: `docker build hal/chefs  -t chef:trialbuild` to build image

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#options

Comment: that command you gave, gave me an error:
unable to prepare context: path "hal/chefs" not found

Comment: `hal/chefs` is your directory on your PC